# How can I find a word and select the following input?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to select the input following a given word?
For example, `findInputAfter("Firstname")` returns input 1 and `findInputAfter("Lastaname")` returns input 2.

This is to fill an online form that contains no label.

Thanks!

```
<div id="form-with-simple-text-instead-of-label-before-the-input-field">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="1" />
Lastname: <input type="text" name="2" />
</div>
```

PS : This is not my website and I can't access the source code so I can't add label or id to form...

Comment: What have you tried? Please see [ask], then revise to show your code.

Comment: All inputs should have labels anyway, for accessibility.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but I didn't code the website, I just want to access the inputs with a script to fill them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the website is not mine. I can't edit the source code.

Comment: since you would know beforehand which input you want to input to, why not just selector on `input[name="1"]`? you can map the selectors back to sane labels like Firstname with a simple object https://playcode.io/1031249

Comment: const inputs = document.getElementsByName("input_name");